# NA's generated when subsetting data in R

Tags: r, filter, subset, na

I am having this problem and it is driving me crazy. I try to filter data in R using the following command:

`data <- data[data$v1 != "T",]`

This works as far as the filtered data cotain the desired number of rows. However, since "v1" contains NA's, all observations with v1 = NA before filtering now consist only of NA's in all the columns.

Anybody knows why this is happending?

Thanks a lot already.

Comment: We can do `data[data$v1 != "T" & !is.na(data$v1),]`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NA is not comparable to actual values. The answer to 'is this equal to "T"' for NA is idk, so the whole row becomes NAs. The way to avoid it is either by excluding NAs as @akrun suggested, or by explicitly looking for NAs if you wish to retain those rows:

```
data[data$v1 != "T" | is.na(data$v1),]
```